# Install jpeg 2000 on Windows 10

Tags: testing, installation, jpeg2000

I want to investigate a new application for JPEG 2000 encoding and decoding. I downloaded openjpeg-master and managed to cobble together the ability to cmake the files. After a bunch of grinding, this resulted in the following output:
"Build files have been written to: C: openjpeg-master/build
\build> "

Any "normal" Unix installations have a multi-step installation like this:

"UNIX/LINUX - MacOS (terminal) - WINDOWS (cygwin, MinGW)
To build the library, type from source tree directory:

mkdir build

cd build

cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

make

Binaries are then located in the 'bin' directory.

To install the library, type with root privileges:

make install

make clean
To build the html documentation, you need doxygen to be installed on your system. It will create an "html" directory in TOP_LEVEL/build/doc)

make doc"

But the Windows 10 equivalent is unclear, to put the most charitable spin on it. You can find it here: "https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md"
Some questions arise:

1. is there a better starting place for installing JPEG 2000 that actually shows me how to install it and run the tests?
2. if not, how do I get from the build files to installing the libraries and making the test programs?
3. Is there more information I can dig out that would help to answer these questions?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm allergic to Visual Studio, I overlooked a nice tutorial specifying how to install something as complex as openjpeg by direct clone from github. However, in desperation, I found it and it worked. It is Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.3. I needed only to use -DTHIRDPARTY to get the third party libraries installed. There is a drop-down menu to build and install OPENJPEG. All I need to do now is figure out how to compile and run the utilities that invoke the installed libraries ...

Answer (score 0):

1. actually, the complete line to add was -DBUILD_THIRDPARTY:bool=true.
2. Somewhere in my frantic random search for a way forward, I remember seeing the thought that to make the tests work, I merely need to find files like *.vsproj and run them a separate VS solutions. Some random guesswwork with .vdproj files in src/bin/... hasn't produced anything good. Is there not a document somewhere showing how to run the tests?